# "Lieber, sehr geehrter Herr X": wie antworten?

Tags: salutation, formality, letter

Folgende Situation:

Sie kontaktieren Firma A in einer geschäftlichen Angelegenheit. Der Telefonanruf wird an Frau B duchgestellt, gemeinsam mit ihrem Ehemann geschäftsführende Gesellschafterin des Unternehmens. Im Anschluss an das Telefongespräch mailen Sie ihr eine Zusammenfassung, dabei verwenden Sie die Anrede "Sehr geehrte Frau B".

Sie mailt postwendend zurück, mit der Anrede "Lieber, sehr geehrter Herr X...".

Bis vor wenigen Stunden hatten Sie weder vom Unternehmen noch von Frau B gehört, Sie haben auch keine gemeinsamen Bekannten. Sie sind gleichzeitig erfreut und besorgt.

Erfreut, da es als gutes Zeichen für die Geschäftsanbahnung zu werten ist, dass sie eine so freundliche Anrede wählt. Besorgt, da Ihnen nicht wohl dabei ist, eine bis dato unbekannte (und verheiratete!) Frau als "Liebe..." anzureden, auch wenn direkt danach noch ein "sehr geehrte" folgt.

Wenn Sie aber in der Antwort nur "Sehr geehrte Frau B" schreiben, könnte sie meinen, Sie wären steif und verknöchert, eventuell sogar bewusst unfreundlich. Vielleicht noch interessant zu wissen, das Unternehmen ist im weiteren Sinne im Bereich der Schönen Künste tätig.

Wie entscheiden Sie sich?

Comment: Da Deutsch nicht meine Muttersprache ist, verstehe ich kaum das Problem. Ich meine, wenn man „Liebe(r)” schreibt, man meint das nicht ernst, oder? Auf Englisch "Dear" hat keine andere Bedeutung als eine angenehmere Anrede. Oder vielleicht "Dear" kann nicht so einfach von „Liebe(r)” ersetzt werden.

Comment: Ich google Ihr Foto. ;)

Comment: @c.p. *"Dear" kann nicht so einfach von „Liebe(r)” ersetzt werden.* So ist es. In einem deutschen Brief bedeutet "Liebe(r)..." etwas anderes als "Dear..." in einem englischen. Nach meinem Dafürhalten ist "Liebe(r)..." für die Kommunikation zwischen Eheleuten/Lebenspartnern, Verwandten und guten Freunden reserviert. Ausnahme: "Mein(e) liebe(r) X". Kann auch zwischen Personen, die sich nur dem Namen nach kennen, verwendet werden. Ist dann entweder verbindlich-liebenswürdig (nach austriakischer Art) oder gönnerhaft-herablassend gemeint.

Comment: +1, wichtige, feinsinnige Information.

Comment: Zwar bin ich jetzt nicht "so klug als wie zuvor", denn die Antworten haben mich klüger gemacht. Aber genauso gespalten. Mal eine ganz laienhafte Off-Topic-Frage eines Nicht-Informatikers: kann man einen Computer ebenso in Verwirrung stürzen wie mich durch diese Anrede? Konkret, kann ich eine Instruktion hinschreiben, die keine Regel wie "für jedes DO muss es ein WHILE geben" verletzt (man verzeihe mir das vllt. schlecht gewählte Beispiel), aber trotzdem die Maschine in einen unentscheidbaren Konflikt zwingt?

Comment: @EugeneSeidel Wenn Windows meldet `the memory at 0000000 could not be 'read'` muss etwas ähnliches passiert sein.

Comment: Ihr Fall entstand ziemlich sicher dadurch, daß sie erst ‚Lieber’ schrieb, sich dann aber auf ‚sehr geehrter’ besann. Dies kann jedem passieren. Ich würde reagieren als stünde dort nur der mir willkommenere Teil. Welcher dies ist, entscheiden Sie. Viel schlimmer habe ich es erlebt als ich einmal schrieb ‚sehr geehrter Herr Professor‘ und die Antwort mit ‚Hey‘ begann. Hätte ich ‚geschächtet sei Er, Wicht!‘ zurückgeschrieben, wäre mir eine Zusammenarbeit mit einem unterbelichteten Ar... erspart geblieben.

Answer (score 9):

Im geschäftlichen Bereich sollte es immer „sehr geehrte/r“ sein. Wenn der Kommunikationspartner das anders sieht, ist das sein gutes Recht. Es ist aber nicht zu erwarten, dass er dieses Nichtstandardverhalten auf seine Kommunikationspartner projiziert.

Man sollte also mit

> Sehr geehrte Frau B,

antworten und im Folgenden rein sachlich bleiben.

Ich kenne mich im Bereich der schönen Künste nicht aus, die Sprache sollte jedenfalls diesem Bereich angemessen sein.

Die Formulierung ist jedenfalls nicht unfreundlich. Sie mag knöchern oder steif wirken, aber im geschäftlichen Bereich muss man davon ausgehen, dass der Kommunikationspartner derartige, etwaige Eindrücke angesichts der Standardkonformität der Formulierung verdrängt.

Comment: +1, einleuchtend argumentiert.

Answer (score 4):

Ich gehe davon aus, daß der lieben Frau B sehr wohl klar ist,
daß im geschäftlichen Verkehr die Anrede "Sehr geehrte(r)
Frau/Herr ..." üblich ist. Tief in ihrer Künstlerseele
erscheint ihr dies aber als zu steif, zu förmlich, zu
unpersönlich.

Nun gibt es zwei Möglichkeiten: Die eine ist, daß sie
regelmäßig diese Mischform wählt, um so auch in einer
eigentlich formellen Anrede etwas emotionale Wärme
unterzubringen. Die andere Möglichkeit wäre, daß es sich
um einen Versuchsballon handelt: Sie redet Dich mit
"Sehr geehrter Herr" an, macht aber gleichzeitig klar,
daß von ihrer Seite aus nichts dagegen spricht, zu
"Liebe(r) Frau/Herr ..." überzugehen, und läßt Dir nun
die Wahl, so oder so zu reagieren (vgl. auch
[diesen Text](http://www.sekada-daily.de/aktuelles/tipp/achtung-fettnaepfchen-lieber-oder-sehr-geehrter-herr.html)).

Für Dich bedeutet das: Mit "Sehr geehrte Frau" machst Du
bestimmt nichts verkehrt; wenn Du aber mit "Liebe Frau"
antwortest, kann sie sich auch nicht beklagen.

Man sollte die Anrede "Lieber Herr ..." nicht
überbewerten. Ich weiß nicht, wie die Gepflogenheiten
unter Künstlern und Kunstverlegern sind. Wenn es in diesem
Bereich üblich ist, sehr schnell zum Du wechseln, dann
erscheint natürlich die Anrede "Sehr geehrter Herr" umso
förmlicher, und man sucht deshalb nach einer Zwischenstufe.
So kenne ich es jedenfalls aus dem
akademischen Bereich (genauer: Mathematik/Informatik),
wo die Anrede "Liebe(r) Frau/Herr ..." auch relativ
häufig ist.

Comment: +1, einleuchtend argumentiert. Guter Link zu Ratgeberseite. Ja, "Guten Tag" (und sogar "Hallo") sind brauchbare Alternativen.

Answer (score 4):

Die Briefanrede "Liebe(r)..." ist keineswegs, wie du in einem Kommentar gemeint hast, für die (vertraute) Kommunikation zwischen Eheleuten/Lebenspartnern, Verwandten und guten Freunden reserviert.

Es ist vielmehr **eine "förmliche" Anrede im informellen Bereich**, die durch zahlreiche Zusätze feinmoduliert werden kann, wie es dem tatsächlichen (auch tagesaktuellen!) Verhältnis der Kommunikationspartner entspricht. Eine weitere Rolle spielen der Anlass (die Kommunikationsabsicht) und das Medium (Brief oder Karte, Mail, SMS etc.).

> 1. *Lieber Markus! Liebe Eva!*

ist die grundsätzliche Anrede zwischen Verwandten, Freunden, Bekannten, Bürokollegen, Vereinskollegen, Facebookfreunden etc., aber unter Umständen auch zwischen intimen Partnern. Wer hier *Liebe(r)* verwendet, macht keinen Fehler, ohne sich dabei viel denken zu müssen. Wenn man sich sonst per *Hallo*, *Hi* etc. anspricht, dann zeigt das formellere *Liebe(r)*, dass man schon länger nichts voneinander gehört hat, dass ein Geburtstag ansteht oder man ein ernsteres Anliegen hat; in einem solchen Fall entschließt man sich vielleicht auch dazu, einen Brief statt einer Mail zu schreiben. Wenn sich Liebende, Ehe- bzw. Lebenspartner etc. mit *Liebe(r)* ansprechen, wo sie bisher Wendungen wie *Mein(e) Liebste(r)", "Hi du Süße(r)" oder was auch immer verwendet haben, ist wahrscheinlich Feuer am Dach.

> 2a. *Lieber Herr Mustermann,*

signalisiert eine eigenmächtige Annäherung des Schreibers gegenüber dem Adressaten. Aus irgendeinem Grund ist der Adressat in der schwächeren Position:

- Vorgesetzter gegenüber Untergebenem (in einem hierarchisch und
  formell geführten Unternehmen)
- Auftraggeber gegenüber Auftragnehmer, meist mit geringerem Bildungsstand
- Nachbar, der einem anderen aus einem
  bestimmten Grund die Höflichkeitsfloskel "Sehr geehrter" verweigert
- etc.

Es kommt vor, dass z.B. ein Uni-Professor einen anderen, den er zwar kennt, mit dem er aber nicht per Du ist, auf diese Weise anredet, und es kann vielleicht auch, das ist nur meine Vermutung, in anderen Chefetagen vorkommen. Nachweislich schreiben mittlerweile aber Studenten mit dieser Anrede an ihre Professoren. Es hängt sehr vom Ton und Inhalt der Nachricht ab, ob das bloße Formlosigkeit, eine Respektverweigerung oder eine neutrale gemeinsame Basis impliziert. Normalerweise würde man den Titel einfügen.

> 2b. *Guten Tag, liebe Frau Reisig! Hallo lieber Herr Giese!*

Das Anfügen einer Grußformel gibt der Anrede einen freundlichen, informellen Ton ohne die Grenzüberschreitung von 2a. Solche Anredeformeln findet man z.B. oft bei beruflichen Erstkontakten zwischen Filmschaffenden.

> 2c. *Liebe Marianne Huber, ...*

signalisiert einen Statusunterschied (z.B. Uni-Lehrer gegenüber einem Studenten), wirkt etwas dürr und "auf den Punkt kommend", aber nicht übergriffig.

> 3. *Sehr geehrte Frau Institutsvorständin, liebe Susanne!*

schreibt man (zumindest in Österreich) in einer beruflichen Mitteilung an Höhergestellte, mit denen man gleichzeitig befreundet ist. Genannt werden dabei nur Funktionsbezeichnungen, nicht der/die Titel.

> *Lieber, sehr geehrter Herr X!*

ist eine sehr interessante Formel. Das "Lieber" betont Respekt und ein (gewünschtes) besonderes Verhältnis dir gegenüber in einer ansonsten formelhaften allgemeinen Anrede, das "sehr geehrter Herr X" relativiert das "lieber" im Sinn eines korrekten Verhältnisses zwischen Geschäftspartnern. Du musst keinesfalls Bedenken haben, der Frau "zu nahe" zu kommen, wenn du "Liebe Frau Y" schreibst, aber genauso wenig ist es unhöflich, nur "Sehr geehrte Frau Y" zu schreiben, vor allem, wenn du Kunde bei der Firma bist. Auch hier hängt es natürlich wieder vom Ton und vom Inhalt des Schreibens ab, ob die Anrede plump vertraulich oder abkühlend wirkt.

Man darf nicht vergessen, dass die Schlussformel genauso wichtig ist wie die Anrede und beide zusammen eine Einheit bilden, was die Aussage über Verhältnis, Intimität, aktuelle "Wetterlage", Anliegen bzw. Anlass etc. betrifft. Für Geschäftsbriefe ist "Mit freundlichen Grüßen" das Minimum, das man durch eine "lebendigere" Formel vorteilhaft aufhellen kann.

Answer (score 1):

Vermutlich, je nach Wichtigkeit und Art des Themas, würde ich auf *Liebe* verzichten, und im weiteren Verlauf versuchen, anhand freundlicher, persönlicherer, evtl. lustiger Formulierungen meine Offenheit zu beweisen.

> Sehr geehrte Frau B.

**Uwe**s Vorschläge:

> Vielen Dank für Ihre freundliche Antwort

oder

> ...
>   Mit herzlichen Grüßen

---

(*Vielen Dank für Ihre liebreizende/liebevolle Antwort.* sollte man nicht schreiben, das geht zu weit.)

Wahrscheinlich war das *Lieber, sehr geehrter* unbewusst, unüberlegt, so dass man darauf nicht direkt anspielen sollte.

Anstatt *Liebe* ließe sich auch etwas anderes verwenden, z. B.:

> Hallo, sehr geehrte Frau B

Wahrscheinlich ist das sogar die beste Lösung, da es zwar persönlicher, aber doch ohne *Liebe* ist. Je nachdem legt man unter Künstlern aber auch mehr Wert auf Originalität als auf Standard, so dass man sich auch ausgefallenere Formen erlauben kann, vor allem da die Schreiberin mit *Lieber* ja auch eine gewisse Offenheit zeigt, dank der auch eine etwas ungeschickte Begrüßungsformel der Geschäftsbeziehung keinen Abbruch tun wird.

Comment: "liebreizend" oder "liebevoll" geht nicht. Da fühlt sie sich auf den Arm genommen (nicht ganz zu Unrecht). Schon der Satz "Vielen Dank für ihre freundliche Antwort" würde eine persönliche Note hineinbringen. Möglicherweise könnte man auch die Schlußformel etwas variieren, also statt "Mit freundlichen Grüßen" vielleicht "Mit herzlichen Grüßen".

Comment: Danke für die Rückmeldung. "liebreizend" und "liebevoll" liegt wirklich daneben....

Comment: @Speravir Danke für die Korrektur. Ich habe das wohl zu schnell geschrieben... (In der Schweiz, wo ich bin, verwendet man übrigens kein ß)

Comment: @gamag Upps. Ich habe nicht nachgesehen, wo Du herkommst. Man könnte rein theoretisch, ist nur komplizierter als mit deutscher Tasteratur. ;-) Aber im Ernst: Da Du explizit von Uwes Vorschlägen geschrieben hast, hätte ich zumindest diesen einen Teil auch dann geändert, wenn ich nachgesehen hätte.

Comment: @Speravir es waren ja auch sonst einige Fehler, vielen Dank jedenfalls.